# Can multi-record custom field sets be sequenced so most recent ones appear first in the UI?

Tags: multi-record

We use a multi-record custom set, with a large number of fields.  Some contacts have 4 or more of these records so the display gets cumbersome, with the most recently created always shown last.  So there's lots of scrolling to make sure the correct, most recent record is retrieved from the bottom of the list.  Is there a way of reversing this sequence so the most recently created is first in the list?  Perhaps adding an additional MySql index to these records?